# Cartesian/Parametric 3d equation of a cheese twist?

Tags: 3d, surfaces, parametric

Hi I'm looking for the equation of a cheese twist in 3d (either parametric or cartesian)... Can be multiple planes but was wondering if anyone had any idea to execute something like this? Thanks

e.g.
[image: Cheese Twist]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid

Comment: All the sudden I'm hungry.